# Solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n-1)+n^2$

Tags: algorithms, summation, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Solve the recurrence 
$$T(1) = 1, T(2) = 1, T(3) = 1,T(n) = 2T(n-1)+n^2, n > 3$$

I have now,
$$T(n) = 2T(n-1)+^2 $$
$$= 2(2T(n-2)+(n-1)^2+n^2$$
$$=4T(n-2)+2(n-1)^2+n^2$$
$$....$$
$$2^iT(n-i)+\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}=2^{k}(n-k)^2$$
$$2^{n-1}T(1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}=2^{k}(n-k)^2=2^{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k(n-k)^2$$

Can anyone help.

The @all

Comment: I don't think a closed form exists because the recurrence is dependent _only_ on the current term and the previous term and $T(2),T(3)$ doesn't satisfy the recurrence. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : notice that the recurrence relation is only for n > 3, so there is no problem

Comment: Yes, but the recurrence depends on only one previous term, that was the reason for my previous comment. @Tryss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Less words, more facts. Let

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 1} T(n)\,z^n.\tag{1}$$
The recurrence relation hence gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(z) &=& 2\sum_{n\geq 4} T(n-1)\,z^{n} + (z+z^2+z^3)+\sum_{n\geq 4}n^2 z^n\\&=&2z\sum_{n\geq 3}T(n)\,z^n+(z+z^2+z^3)+\frac{z^4 (16 - 23 z + 9 z^2)}{(1-z)^3}\\&=&2z\left(f(z)-z-z^2\right)+(z+z^2+z^3)+\frac{z^4 (16 - 23 z + 9 z^2)}{(1-z)^3}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and it follows that:
$$ f(z) = \frac{z \left(1-4 z+5 z^2+15 z^3-25 z^4+10 z^5\right)}{(1-z)^3 (1-2z)}\tag{3}$$
so, by partial fraction decomposition, we have:

> $$ \forall n>2,\qquad  T(n) = 7\cdot 2^{n-1}-(n+2)^2-2. \tag{4}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you obtained $T(n)$ from the partial fraction decomposition? I guess adding coefficients for the series expansions of each summand?

Comment: @Christoph: exactly. There are two singularities giving different contributes: the simple pole in $z=\frac{1}{2}$ gives the $2^n$ term and the triple pole in $z=1$ gives the polynomial terms. They are just routine computations, not really interesting in themselves.

Comment: You have inspired me.  I think I'll begin all of my future proofs with *less words, more facts*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation.  There is a standard procedure for solving these when the non-homogeneous term has a particular form, namely a polynomial, an exponential, or the product of a polynomial and an exponential.

In your equation, the non-homogeneous term is $F(n)=n^2$.

The first step is to find the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation, obtained by replacing the non-homogeneous term with 0.

In your equation, the associated homogeneous equation is $T(n)=2T(n-1)$.  Suppose the general solution is $u_c(n)$ (also called the *complementary function*).

The second step is to propose a solution based on the homogeneous term.

Since your non-homogeneous term is a polynomial of degree 2, you propose a general polynomial of degree 2.  So your proposed solution in this case is $u_p(n)=an^2+bn+c$.

The third step is to substitute the proposed solution into the non-homogeneous equation and use the resulting equation to find $a,b,$ and $c$.

The fourth step is to construct the general solution to your equation equation from $u_c(n)$ and $u_p(n).$ This is $T(n)=u_p(n)+u_c(n)$.

As I mentioned, this is a fairly standard method, and can probably be found in most textbooks that cover linear recurrence relations.

Answer (score 1):

A linear recurrence of first order, which can always be "solved" (as long as finding closed forms of some ugly sums is possible).

The general form is:

$$
a_{n + 1} = f(n) a_n + g(n)
$$

where $a_0$ is given.

Divide by the *summing factor*:

$$
S_n = \prod_{0 \le k \le n} f(k)
$$

Note this is valid as long as $f(k) \ne 0$ over the relevant range.

Thus:

$\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n + 1}}{S_n} - \frac{a_n}{S_{n - 1}}
  &= \frac{g(n)}{S_n} \\
\sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1}
  \left(
    \frac{a_{k + 1}}{S_k} - \frac{a_k}{S_{k - 1}}
  \right)
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{g(k)}{S_k} \\
\frac{a_n}{S_{n - 1}} - a_0
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{g(k)}{S_k} \\
a_n
  &= a_0 S_{n - 1} + s_{n - 1} \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{g(k)}{S_k}
\end{align}$

In your particular case $f(n) = 2$ and $g(n) = (n + 1)^2$, $S_n = 2^n$,
so that:

$\begin{align}
T(n)
  &= 2^{n - 1} T(0)
       + 2^{n - 1} \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{(k + 1)^2}{2^k} \\
  &= 2^{n - 1} T(0)
       + 2^n \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} \frac{(k + 1)^2}{2^{k + 1}} \\
  &= 2^{n - 1} T(0)
       + 2^{n - 1} \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \frac{k^2}{2^{k - 1}}
\end{align}$

The resulting sum is somewhat tricky. We know that:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} z^k
  &= \frac{1 - z^{n + 1}}{1 - z} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z}
  \left(
    z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z}
      \sum_{0 \le k \le n} z^k
  \right)
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^2 z^{k - 1} \\
  &= \frac{1 + (n z - n - 1) z^n}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align}$

Evaluate this at $z = 1/2$ to get your sum:

$$
2^{-n + 1} (2^{n + 1} - n - 2)
$$

so the final result is:

$$
T(n) = 2^{n - 1} T(0) + 2^{n + 1} - n - 2
$$